# Call a separate Java class to set up or change data without asking for a return or setting up an object

Tags: java, class, object, methods, subroutine

I'm trying to split a java program into .java files which are called from the main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
//Call code in a separate .java file which sets up an array of objects.
//Call code to change the object values in a certain way i times
//Call code to do some calculations
//Call code to display some info
}
```

All the guidance I have come across which is broadly analogous to calling a separate piece of code to do something refers to either creating objects (eg `MyObject myobject1 = new MyObject();`); or getting returned values (eg `x=myMethod(datain);`), rather than simply creating or changing data.

Have I missed something, or is there no way to avoid putting all the creating/changing code in the same main .java file without artificially creating objects or getting pointless returns such as `Boolean datacreated = createMyData()`

In my simple Fortran derived world I would be able to split up the main program as follows:

```
call SetUpMyData
call ChangeMyData
call SomeOtherSub
//etc
```

Comment: Java is object oriented language. One can try to emulate procedural way in Java, but it won't be idiomatic Java.

Comment: Plus, you pseudo-code does not show any data structures being passed around, only calls to methods. I hope, this does not imply your program will work solely with global data, w/o using local data structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly write programs this way. Just make all your methods and state `public` and `static`. You will be able to use them from anywhere in your program:

```
public class Main {
    public static int data[];

    public static void initialize() {
        Main.data = new int[100];
    }

    public static void print() {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Main.data));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main.print();
        Main.initialize();
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach, is that it's more error prone and harder to analyze. If you avoid global variables, compiler will catch many mistakes:

```
public static int[] initialize() {
    return new int[100];
}

public static void print(int[] data) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int data[];
    Main.print(data); // compile error - data is not initialized
    data = Main.initialize(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a way sort of. If you want to have a seperate class changing the variables in your main class, without using a return statement or anything, you have to define them as global variables. You do this by creating them above your main method, like this:

```
class Main {
    public static int sampleNumber = 0;
    public static String sampleString; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SupportClass.setVariables();
    }
}
```

Then in your SupportClass, where you want to change the values from the first class, reference them with `Classname.varaiblename`:

```
class SupportClass {
    public static void setVariables() {
        Main.sampleNumber = 20;
        Main.sampleString = "This works!";
    }
}
```

But in all honesty, this is NOT a good way to do this. If you don't want to clutter up your main method, add a helper method at the bottom of your main class that sets the variables. This isn't a very usual way to set variables.

Answer (score 0):

Well, while you can do some of the things you should first of all change your thinking to be more object oriented. There you would have a constructor to set up a object. Or you would call multiple mothods on the same object - if they work on the same data.

```
main(String[] args) {
  World world = new World(); // setup different fields
  world.prepare(); // modify some fields
  world.calculate();
  System.out.println(world.getResult()); // or world.printResult();
}
```

You could hide some of the data dependencies with singletons or fields, but you should not as it makes it hard to follow the program.

If you want to structure a larger calculation into sub routines, you would do the same with private methods:

```
class MyExperiment {
  long sum, a, b;

  void doExperiment() {
    init();
    simulate();
    printResults();
  }

  private void init() {
    a = 1;
    b = 1;
  }

  private void simulate() {
    sum = a + b;
 }

 private void printResult() {
   System.out.println("sum=" + sum);
 }
}
```

You would start it with `new MyExperiment().doExperiment()`

Comment: Many thanks for this eckes (and to others who have responded) I'm basically trying to avoid having thousands of lines of code in one place but I take the points about making code more error prone and trying to adjust my thinking. I suppose the general message is that splitting the code up should be avoided/done with care. One quick question: In the example above, if I have objects stored in an array (eg r[1], r[2] ...etc. where r[1].x=x1, r[1].y=y1 etc.) how would I declare r[] after the long declaration in class MyExperiment so the routine simulate() could access/change r[1].x, r[1].y etc.?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but defining a field in the class is visible to all methods in that class, no matter where it is defined. (outside of the methods of course). (And no, having large unsplit code is not a good idea :)

Comment: OK, I suppose I should split the code but avoid putting it in different classes unless it is appropriate. I think I'm getting there! Thanks again.